# Обновить данные в mySQL

Tags: php, javascript, mysql

Здравствуйте!
Есть код в файле settings.php:

```
<?$day = "<select onChange='setting(this)';>";

$day .= "<option value='r'>".trans('r')."</option>";

$day .= "<option value='ho'>".trans('ho')."</option>";

$day .= "<option value='kr'>".trans('kr')."</option>";

$day .= "<option value='do'>".trans('do')."</option>";

$day .= "<option value='v'>".trans('v')."</option>";

$day .="</select>";?>
```

Код выбора элемента на javascript:

```
function setting(select) {
val = select.options[select.selectedIndex].value;

alert (val);

}
```

Есть некий файл update_settings.php:
Тут будет располагаться обновление данных БД.
Такой вопрос: можно как-то реализовать обновление данных в БД путём передачи данных в javascript? А в файле update_settings их REQUESтом перехватить и сделать обновление в БД. Возможно этот как-то реализовать? Если да, то подскажите, как, пожалуйста. Спасибо.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Через jQuery.

Подгрузить библиотеку jQuery:

```
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/latest/jquery.js"></script>
```

Добавить обработчик события change для select:

```
<script>
$("#trans").change(function() {
    var tval = $(this).val();
    $.ajax({
        url: '/ajax/update.php?trans='+tval,
        success: function(data){
            alert(data);            
        }            
    });
});      
</script>
```

Ваш код вывода php:

```
  <?php
  $day = "<select id='trans'>";
  $day .= "<option value='r'>".trans('r')."</option>";
  $day .= "<option value='ho'>".trans('ho')."</option>";
  $day .= "<option value='kr'>".trans('kr')."</option>";
  $day .= "<option value='do'>".trans('do')."</option>";
  $day .= "<option value='v'>".trans('v')."</option>";
  $day .="</select>";
  ?>
```

Код /ajax/update.php

```
<?php

$trans = $_GET['trans'];

...
if(Запрос обновления таблицы БД){
    echo 'Record was updated!';
}

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<select id="category" name="category">
<option value="1" name="123">1</option>
<option value="2" name="456">2</option>
<option value="3" name="789">3</option>
<option value="4" name="562">4</option>
</select>
<div id="categoryDisplay"></div>

**AJAX**

$(function(){
   $("#category").change(function() {
      var styleValue = $(this).val();
    $("#categoryDisplay").load('fuck.php', {style: styleValue});
   });
}).change();
```

**fuck.php**

```
            <?php

$style = $_POST['style'];

switch($style){
case "1": $category = "Выберите категорию";
            break;

case "2": $category = "хай 1";;
            break;

case "3": $category = "хай 2";
            break;

case "4": $category = "хай 3";
            break;
default: exit(); break;
}

echo <<< MyObject
{$category}
MyObject;

?>
```

Comment: Огромное Вам спасибо, буду сейчас разбираться)

Comment: Галочку поставить не забудьте.

Comment: alexkad, а этот скрипт будет выполняться при смене value или к нему кнопку делать надо?
а то у меня ничего не происходит =(

Comment: Можете изменять, только Вам придется еще изменить в php в case "value".